# Keycloak: HTTP request with Client Credentials always returns 'login' page

Tags: authentication, client, keycloak, credentials

We're developing spring boot service and we managed to setup an OAuth2 with Keycloak and Google as OpenID provider. This works fine in a browser.

Now, I need to create a Spring Boot client for this service.

I understand the Google OpenID is useless here, so I configured a new Client in Keycloak with Access Type : Confidential, Service Accounts Enabled and Client Authenticator : Client Id and Secret.

Problem: When I send a HTTP request to the secured endpoint I receive the Access Token, but only a 'login page', not the expected result from the endpoint.

[image: screenshot from Insomnia (same behavior in Postman)]

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Edit1: keycloak config
[image: keycloak config]

Comment: Share the screenshot of your keycloak configuration

Comment: @Abhijeet done (btw I described the config in text). thank u.

Answer (score 0):

creating the keycloak from scratch solved my issue. I guess we had set something wrong…

- We thought we only need one Client for both browser authentication and machine-to-machine, but we need 1 Client per authentication type.